# "sudo pwd" returns "/root"

Tags: root, sudo, environment

I'm having a problem with the `sudo` command. When I launch `sudo pwd`, the output is `/root` instead of the directory from which the `sudo` command was launched.

The consequence is that when I try to run a script as a sudoer, it doesn't work because it doesn't run it with its full path.

Since the problem doesn't exist when I'm logged in as root, I deduce that the problem comes from the `sudo` application. Moreover, there is no issue with my `PATH` variable.

I tried removing `sudo` (`yum remove sudo`) and removed the `/etc/sudoers.d` repository and the `/etc/sudoers` files before reinstalling `sudo`, but the problem persists.

**My shell outputs (toto.sh contains "echo toto")**

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ ./toto.sh 
toto

[admin@localhost ~]$ sudo ./toto.sh 
-bash: ./toto.sh: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

[admin@localhost ~]$ su
[root@localhost admin]# ./toto.sh
toto

[root@localhost admin]# exit
[admin@localhost ~]$ sudo pwd
/root**
```

Could you please help me? BTW, I use CentOS 7.

Comment: You can use `sudo -s` instead.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40719/stay-at-same-working-directory-when-changing-to-sudo